# Match 2 sets of points in 3D space using different error metric

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

I have two sets of points $A=\{a_1, a_2, ... , a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1, b_2, ... b_n\}$ in 3D space. I am looking for a rigid-body transformation $M$ (just rotation + translation) that bests fits points from set $A$ to set $B$. The points are already paired, i.e. I want to minimise the error between $a_i$ and $b_i$ for all $i$.

**But here is the twist.**

I do *not* want to minimize the square distance $\sum_i |Mb_i-a_i|^2$ -- for that I would use Kabsch algorithm or similar.

Instead, for every $i$ I am given a *direction of interest* -- A normalized 3D vector $d_i$. I want to minimise the error along those directions, that is:

$$ \sum_i |(Mb_i - a_i)\cdot d_i|^2$$

In effect the points $a_i$ and $Mb_i$ may be arbitrary far in the direction perpendicular to the given direction of interest $d_i$.

Do you have any ideas how I could incorporate Kabsch to minimize this? Or maybe I should attack it with a completely different algorithm?

---

Edit: alternative formulation. Instead of points and directions $(a_i, d_i)$ we can consider planes given by formula $A_ix+B_iy+C_iz+D_i=0$. Then, we want to minimize a product of a row-vector $[A_i\ B_i\ C_i\ D_i]$, the $4\times4$ transformation matrix $M$ and a point $b_i$ given in homogeneous coordinates:

$$\sum_i\left|[A_i\ B_i\ C_i\ D_i]Mb_i\right|^2$$

---

Currently I just iteratively project $b_i$ onto a line $a_i + td_i$ obtaining $b'_i$ and then use Kabsch for sets $A$ and $B'$. This slowly converges to more-or-less what I need. This is slow, however, and probably counter-examples exists why this is not that great idea.

It is slow, because if $b_i$ already lies on a plane defined by $(a_i, d_i)$ it effectively acts as a "dampening force", preventing the whole system to move in the direction perpendicular to $d_i$, which may be beneficial from the perspective of other point pairs.

Comment: I think that some kind of gradient descent or newton gauss is indeed the way to proceed.